# How to resolve "Access to requested resource is denied"?

Tags: amazon-web-services, postman, amazon-selling-partner-api

I am getting the following when sending a marketplaceParticipations request to sellers/v1/marketplaceParticipations via Postman after following instructions and examples provided at https://developer-docs.amazon.com/sp-api/docs/connecting-to-the-selling-partner-api

```
{
    "errors": [
        {
            "message": "Access to requested resource is denied.",
            "code": "Unauthorized",
            "details": ""
        }
    ]
}
```

We have registered a self-authorized app client in Draft status which has a user ARN IAM attached as described at [https://developer-docs.amazon.com/sp-api/docs/registering-your-application.Ï](https://developer-docs.amazon.com/sp-api/docs/registering-your-application.%C3%8F)

I've checked the inline and role policies for the ARN IAM. They are exactly as described at https://developer-docs.amazon.com/sp-api/docs/creating-and-configuring-iam-policies-and-entities#step-4-create-an-iam-role.

We are able to successfully request an LWA access token following the docs at https://developer-docs.amazon.com/sp-api/docs/connecting-to-the-selling-partner-api#step-1-request-a-login-with-amazon-access-token.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please check that the roles of the user you are using allow to make request to that endpoint in your dev profile at https://sellercentral.amazon.com/

As far as I know, the getMarketplaceParticipations doesn't need a Restricted Data Token (RDT). So you must be able to solve it by giving the user the correct roles.

I was able to get them using Postman. It is a good way to check that the request is correctly built and not a programming issue.
[image]

Answer (score 0):

Make sure your APP on Developer Central only selects Roles that are on your Developer Profile (https://sellercentral.amazon.com/developer/register).

Our profile did not have Tax Invoicing, but we were requesting it on the APP, which caused this error to return. Once corrected, the marketplaceParticipations request returned valid data.